# How to disconnect A2DP profile Bluetooth Connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I am working on A2DP connection with headset and other Bluetooth device but when I connect Bluetooth device but when I Disconnect but It didn't disconnect with it. My code is:

```
try {    
    Method connect = mA2dpService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("disconnect", BluetoothDevice.class);
    connect.invoke(device);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you manage with the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found

Call getProfileProxy to get a2dp proxy

```
adapter.getProfileProxy(c, listner, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
```

listenr should implement onA2DPProxyReceived.

Then Callback onA2DPProxyReceived will be called.

```
public void onA2DPProxyReceived (BluetoothA2dp proxy) {
    Method disconnect = null;
    try {
        disconnect = BluetoothA2dp.class.getDeclaredMethod("disconnect", BluetoothDevice.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BluetoothDevice device = findBondedDeviceByName(mBtAdapter, myDevice);
    disconnect.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        int result = disconnect.invoke(proxy,device);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Refer to sites below

- getDeclaredMethod : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredmethod.htm
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.java
- Invoking : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Answer (score 0):

**kotlin**

```
   private fun disconnect(device: BluetoothDevice) {
    val serviceListener: BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener = object :
        BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {}

        @SuppressLint("DiscouragedPrivateApi")
        override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
            val disconnect = BluetoothA2dp::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
                "disconnect",
                BluetoothDevice::class.java
            )
            disconnect.isAccessible = true
            disconnect.invoke(proxy, device)
            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy)
        }
    }
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        .getProfileProxy(mContext, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.A2DP)
}
```

(tested on android 10) [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858146/android-how-to-disconnect-already-connected-bluetooth-device)