# How to disconnect the bound bluetooth device in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, disconnect, a2dp

I can use the following code to unbind, but how do I simply perform disconnection?

```
val pair = device.javaClass.getMethod("removeBond")
pair.isAccessible = true
pair.invoke(device)
```

I use this connection function to connect my headset.

```
val connectMethod = BluetoothA2dp::class.java.getMethod("connect", BluetoothDevice::class.java)
connectMethod.isAccessible = true
connectMethod.invoke(btA2dp, device)
```

I refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858146/android-how-to-disconnect-already-connected-bluetooth-device) but still not working for me.